# JS localstorage после перезагрузки не выдает все значения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, localstorage

Задача состоит в конвертере цены по стандарту - цена в руб., при смене select выбираем другую валюту.

Мой функционал, может быть, далеко не самый правильный и оторван кусками из источников, но мне нужна помощь в решение одной проблемы.
При выборе `option` из `select` - данный выбор сохраняется в `localStorage`.
После перезагрузки страницы, у меня сохраняется и выводится значение логотипа валюты, а вот значение цены не выводится. Необходимо вручную выбирать `select`.

Помогите решить проблему, что бы после перезагрузки стр, цена сразу менялась как валюта.

Мой код:

```js
// LOCALSTORTAGE
function SaveSelectValue(el) {
  localStorage.setItem(el.name, el.value);
}
function LoadSelectValue(el) {
  return localStorage.getItem(el.name);
}

let selectCheck = document.querySelector("[name='selectcheck']");
selectCheck.value = LoadSelectValue(selectCheck);



    window.onload = function () {
        $.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) { // Получаем курс валют
            let s1 = data.Valute.USD.Value; // Получаем Доллар
            let s2 = data.Valute.EUR.Value; // Получаем Евро
            let s3 = data.Valute.JPY.Value; // Получаем Йену
            let c = {'USD':s1, 'EUR':s2, 'JPY':s3, 'RUB':'1'}; // Устанавливаем курс валют

        let val = document.getElementById('val'); // Получаем элемент ввода данных
        let currency1 = document.getElementById('cur1'); // Получаем первый селект
        let currency2 = document.getElementById('cur2'); // Получаем второй селект
        let result = document.getElementsByClassName('convert_result')[0]; // Получаем поле куда будем писать результат
        function summ() { // Делаем функцию
            let z = 0;
            if(currency1.value === currency2.value){ // Если оба значения в селектах равны
                result.innerText = val.value; // То просто вписываем данные из поля ввода
            } else {
                if(currency1.value != 'RUB'){ // Если не равны рублю, то
                    z = val.value/c[currency1.value]; // Переводим сумму в рубли
                    result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((z/c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Делим на курс и округляем до сотых
                }
            }
        }
        currency1.onclick = function () { // При смене первого селекта вызываем функцию.
            summ();
        };

        });
    }

$('select.but').on('change', function() {
  $('#my_field4').val($(this).val());
  $('.my_field4_span').text($(this).find('option:selected').data('myval'));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="but" id="cur1" name="selectcheck" onchange="SaveSelectValue(this)">
                <option name="type" value="RUB" data-myval="₽">RUB</option>
                <option name="type" value="USD" data-myval="$">USD</option>
                <option name="type" value="EUR" data-myval="€">EUR</option>
                <option name="type" value="JPY" data-myval="¥">JPY</option>
            </select>


<input type="number" class="" id="val" value="1000" >
<span class="convert_result">1000</span> <span class="my_field4_span"></span>

    <option id="cur2">RUB</option>
```

Так же код в редакторе: https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/tvc5u948/6/

И на странице, для проверки localStorage: http://locals.synapsepro.site/

Comment: Вы перемешали в коде native JavaScript и jQuery. Не надо.

Comment: то что у меня бардак, я знаю, так как в JS я очень туго соображаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все что нужно было сделать - это под curency1.....
дописать
summ();

- что дает возможность просчитать конвертацию, при загрузки страницы